# When contact is set as primary, the Primary Contact Phone should be updated

Tags: trigger

My code so far has issues. If another account's contact has no primary contact then my code works and updates all related contacts primary phone. But another account's contact has a primary then i get this error.

> Duplicate id in list

Trigger:

```
trigger OSF_Trigger_Contact on Contact (after insert, after update) {
    if(!system.isBatch()){
        OSF_ContactUpdate bh = new OSF_ContactUpdate();
        Database.executeBatch(bh);
    }
}
```

Batch class:

```
public class OSF_ContactUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    public Integer recordsProcessed = 0;
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            'SELECT ID,AccountId, phone, Is_Primary_Contact__c FROM Contact where Is_Primary_Contact__c=true '
        );
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Contact> scope){
        // process each batch of records
        List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
        set<id> accids = new set<id>();
        
        for (Contact contact : scope) {
            if(contact.AccountId !=null){
                accids.add(contact.AccountId);
                
            }
        }
        //here you can add your phone field
        List<contact> conlist = [select id, phone from contact where Accountid=:accids AND Is_Primary_Contact__c=false ];
        for(contact con : conlist){
            for(Contact primcon : scope){
                con.Primary_Contact_Phone__c = primcon.Phone;
                contacts.add(con);
            }
        }
       // update contacts;
        database.update(contacts);
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        System.debug(recordsProcessed + ' records processed. Shazam!');
        AsyncApexJob job = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors,
            JobItemsProcessed,
            TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
            FROM AsyncApexJob
            WHERE Id = :bc.getJobId()];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is simply incorrect.

```
        List<contact> conlist = [select id, phone from contact where Accountid=:accids AND Is_Primary_Contact__c=false ];
        for(contact con : conlist){
            for(Contact primcon : scope){
                con.Primary_Contact_Phone__c = primcon.Phone;
                contacts.add(con);
            }
        }
```

You are ignoring which Contact is associated with which Account. Instead, you're setting every the phone for every Contact associated with every Account that's in scope to the phone of ... every other Contact that's in scope. That's why you're getting

> Duplicate id in list

It's because you're adding *the same Contact* to `contacts` as many times as there are records in `scope`.

You need to take a step back and rethink your logic with respect to your original objective.